# mysql where clause doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a stored procedure in mysql which simply returns the row with ID provided or return all table when no ID is provided.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SLICE_GET`(`slice_id` int)
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM `thesis_db`.`SLICE_INFO`
WHERE (SLICE_ID = `slice_id` OR `slice_id` IS NULL);
END
```

I have used the same idea in ms-sql for years yet it doesn't seem to work for mysql since no matter which ID is passed, the procedure returns entire table.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: You're saying `WHERE SLICE_ID = SLICE_ID`  which will always return true for every single row.

Comment: it seems to me that you are using a column in your filter instead of a parameter: `WHERE slice_id = slice_id or slice_id IS NULL` will always be true for every row

Comment: does `SLICE_ID` and `slice_id` come from different tables? Or `slice_id` is a value?

Comment: You should not use the same name for parameter and for column.

Comment: SLICE_ID is the name of the column. but I get your point, I thought a variable name would be distinguished. thank you

Comment: I'm not sure but check this `SLICE_ID = isnull('slice_id', SLICE_ID)`.

Comment: the problem was the variable name, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to write procedures in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$     
CREATE PROCEDURE `name of procedure` (x CHAR(1), D1 DATE, D2 DATE)  
 BEGIN
SELECT name of columns you want to display
FROM table name
WHERE SLICE_ID= x
OR SLICE_ID IS NULL;
END
$$
```

Note: Moreover mysql is not case sensitive means all caps or all small will not effect it.

delimiter is used to:
 If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises.

By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.